# Overlapped Compute and Transfer in Metal

Tags: gpgpu, metal

Good day,

I am trying to achieve an overlap of data transfer (via DMA engine(s)) to/from a dGPU and execution of kernel(s).

In OpenCL I used to create two command queues. One is to be used for enqueueing data transfer commands and another one for launching kernels.
I have tried the same approach in Metal, however the transfers and executions are always serialized even when there are no dependencies between them. Or at least that is what I see on the timeline in Metal Trace instrument.

Here is my host-side code:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

const unsigned int bufferLength = 100*1024*1024;

@autoreleasepool {
    NSArray<id<MTLDevice>>* devices = MTLCopyAllDevices();

    for(id<MTLDevice> device in devices)
    {
        NSLog(device.description);
    }

    id<MTLDevice> device = devices[0];

    id<MTLLibrary> library = [device newDefaultLibrary];
    id<MTLFunction> kernel = [library newFunctionWithName:@"testKernel"];

    NSError *error = NULL;
    id<MTLComputePipelineState> computePipelineState = [device newComputePipelineStateWithFunction:kernel error:&error];

    if(!computePipelineState)
    {
        NSLog(@"Failed to create compute pipeline state, error %@", error);
        return -1;
    }

    id<MTLCommandQueue> queue0 = [device newCommandQueue];
    id<MTLCommandQueue> queue1 = [device newCommandQueue];
    id<MTLCommandQueue> queue2 = [device newCommandQueue];

    id<MTLCommandQueue> writeQueue = queue0;
    id<MTLCommandQueue> execQueue  = queue2;
    id<MTLCommandQueue> readQueue  = queue1;

    id<MTLBuffer> hostInputBuffer0    = [device newBufferWithLength:bufferLength options:(MTLResourceStorageModeShared)];
    id<MTLBuffer> hostInputBuffer1    = [device newBufferWithLength:bufferLength options:(MTLResourceStorageModeShared)];
    id<MTLBuffer> hostOutputBuffer0   = [device newBufferWithLength:bufferLength options:(MTLResourceStorageModeShared)];
    id<MTLBuffer> hostOutputBuffer1   = [device newBufferWithLength:bufferLength options:(MTLResourceStorageModeShared)];
    id<MTLBuffer> deviceInputBuffer0  = [device newBufferWithLength:bufferLength options:(MTLResourceStorageModePrivate)];
    id<MTLBuffer> deviceInputBuffer1  = [device newBufferWithLength:bufferLength options:(MTLResourceStorageModePrivate)];
    id<MTLBuffer> deviceOutputBuffer0 = [device newBufferWithLength:bufferLength options:(MTLResourceStorageModePrivate)];
    id<MTLBuffer> deviceOutputBuffer1 = [device newBufferWithLength:bufferLength options:(MTLResourceStorageModePrivate)];

    unsigned char *pHostInputData0 = [hostInputBuffer0 contents];
    unsigned char *pHostInputData1 = [hostInputBuffer1 contents];
    for(int i = 0; i < bufferLength; i++)
    {
        pHostInputData0[i] = pHostInputData1[i] = i % 256;
    }

    //        
    // Copy H to D
    //
    id<MTLCommandBuffer> HtoDcommandBuffer0 = [writeQueue commandBuffer];
    HtoDcommandBuffer0.label = @"HtoDcommandBuffer 0";
    id<MTLBlitCommandEncoder> HtoDblitCommandEncoder0 = [HtoDcommandBuffer0 blitCommandEncoder];
    [HtoDblitCommandEncoder0 copyFromBuffer:hostInputBuffer0 sourceOffset:0 toBuffer:deviceInputBuffer0 destinationOffset:0 size:bufferLength];
    [HtoDblitCommandEncoder0 endEncoding];
    [HtoDcommandBuffer0 commit];

    id<MTLCommandBuffer> HtoDcommandBuffer1 = [writeQueue commandBuffer];
    HtoDcommandBuffer1.label = @"HtoDcommandBuffer 1";
    id<MTLBlitCommandEncoder> HtoDblitCommandEncoder1 = [HtoDcommandBuffer1 blitCommandEncoder];
    [HtoDblitCommandEncoder1 copyFromBuffer:hostInputBuffer1 sourceOffset:0 toBuffer:deviceInputBuffer1 destinationOffset:0 size:bufferLength];
    [HtoDblitCommandEncoder1 endEncoding];
    [HtoDcommandBuffer1 commit];

    //        
    // Execute kernel
    //     
    id<MTLCommandBuffer> computeCommandBuffer0 = [execQueue commandBuffer];
    computeCommandBuffer0.label = @"computeCommandBuffer 0";
    id<MTLComputeCommandEncoder> computeCommandEncoder0 = [computeCommandBuffer0 computeCommandEncoder];
    [computeCommandEncoder0 setComputePipelineState:computePipelineState];
    [computeCommandEncoder0 setBuffer:deviceInputBuffer0 offset:0 atIndex:0];
    [computeCommandEncoder0 setBuffer:deviceOutputBuffer0 offset:0 atIndex:1];
    [computeCommandEncoder0 setBytes:&bufferLength length:sizeof(bufferLength) atIndex:2];
    [computeCommandEncoder0 dispatchThreadgroups:MTLSizeMake((bufferLength + 255) / 256, 1, 1) threadsPerThreadgroup:MTLSizeMake(256, 1, 1)];
    [computeCommandEncoder0 endEncoding];
    [computeCommandBuffer0 commit];

    id<MTLCommandBuffer> computeCommandBuffer1 = [execQueue commandBuffer];
    computeCommandBuffer1.label = @"computeCommandBuffer 1";
    id<MTLComputeCommandEncoder> computeCommandEncoder1 = [computeCommandBuffer1 computeCommandEncoder];
    [computeCommandEncoder1 setComputePipelineState:computePipelineState];
    [computeCommandEncoder1 setBuffer:deviceInputBuffer1 offset:0 atIndex:0];
    [computeCommandEncoder1 setBuffer:deviceOutputBuffer1 offset:0 atIndex:1];
    [computeCommandEncoder1 setBytes:&bufferLength length:sizeof(bufferLength) atIndex:2];
    [computeCommandEncoder1 dispatchThreadgroups:MTLSizeMake((bufferLength + 255) / 256, 1, 1) threadsPerThreadgroup:MTLSizeMake(256, 1, 1)];
    [computeCommandEncoder1 endEncoding];
    [computeCommandBuffer1 commit];


    //        
    // Copy D to H
    //       
    id<MTLCommandBuffer> DtoHcommandBuffer0 = [readQueue commandBuffer];
    DtoHcommandBuffer0.label = @"DtoHcommandBuffer 0";
    id<MTLBlitCommandEncoder> DtoHblitCommandEncoder0 = [DtoHcommandBuffer0 blitCommandEncoder];
    [DtoHblitCommandEncoder0 copyFromBuffer:deviceOutputBuffer0 sourceOffset:0 toBuffer:hostOutputBuffer0 destinationOffset:0 size:bufferLength];
    [DtoHblitCommandEncoder0 endEncoding];
    [DtoHcommandBuffer0 commit];

    id<MTLCommandBuffer> DtoHcommandBuffer1 = [readQueue commandBuffer];
    DtoHcommandBuffer1.label = @"DtoHcommandBuffer 1";
    id<MTLBlitCommandEncoder> DtoHblitCommandEncoder1 = [DtoHcommandBuffer1 blitCommandEncoder];
    [DtoHblitCommandEncoder1 copyFromBuffer:deviceOutputBuffer1 sourceOffset:0 toBuffer:hostOutputBuffer1 destinationOffset:0 size:bufferLength];
    [DtoHblitCommandEncoder1 endEncoding];
    [DtoHcommandBuffer1 commit];

    [DtoHcommandBuffer1 waitUntilCompleted];

    unsigned char *pHostOutputData0 = [hostOutputBuffer0 contents];
    unsigned char *pHostOutputData1 = [hostOutputBuffer1 contents];
    for(int i = 0; i < bufferLength; i++)
    {
        if(pHostOutputData0[i] != (i+1) % 256)
            NSLog(@"Mismatch buffer0! idx: %d, expected: %d, actial: %d\n", i, (i+1) % 256, pHostOutputData0[i]);
        if(pHostOutputData1[i] != (i+1) % 256)
            NSLog(@"Mismatch buffer1! idx: %d, expected: %d, actial: %d\n", i, (i+1) % 256, pHostOutputData1[i]);
    }       
}
return 0;
}
```

And the kernel:

```
#include <metal_stdlib>
using namespace metal;

kernel void
testKernel(device unsigned char *inBuf   [[buffer(0)]],
           device unsigned char *outBuf  [[buffer(1)]],
           constant uint &size           [[buffer(2)]],
           uint gid                      [[thread_position_in_grid]])
{
    if(gid >= size)
    {
        return;
    }

    outBuf[gid] = (inBuf[gid] + 1) % 256;
}
```

Comment: I recommend you try the exact opposite of the strategy you're using here. Use a single command buffer, not a separate one for every encoder. Of course, that means you'd use a single command queue. Also, combine your uses of the command encoders: one blit encoder for both H to D copies, one compute encoder for both dispatches, and one blit encoder for both D to H copies. The boundaries between encoders and command buffers are synchronization points. Your "optimizations" may actually be pessimizations.

Comment: Also, in this (presumably simplified) case, the use of staging buffers adds nothing and only requires extraneous work. And, you are failing to wait for the command buffers to complete before reading their results.

Comment: Hi @KenThomases, thank you for the suggestions. I've just tried to combine pairs of blits and executions into single buffers (so that now I have 3 buffers and 3 encoders instead of 6) and use a single command queue. Unfortunately I still see on timeline that blit host to device, execution and blit device to host are serialized. I would expect that the first kernel to start execution while the second buffer is still being copied to device. This is how it works with OpenCL.

Comment: Regarding the staging buffers, you are right, the example is simplified. In real life I am copying the input data from host to GPU, doing several (tenths to hundredths) of kernel launches with intermediate results stored on GPU only (private) buffers and then copying the results back and all that to be repeated in a loop. I've put waitUntilCompleted call to where it should be, lost during editing.

Comment: I have tried to reduce it even further by having only one command buffer and three encoders. Still no luck...

Comment: Hmm. I'm not sure the description of your more complicated real task justifies the use of staging buffers. They would only be needed for double buffering, so to speak. That is, if you needed to modify one set of buffers on the CPU while the GPU was working on the other set. What happens if you eliminate the distinction and the (explicit) copy? Have the GPU work with the shared-mode buffers. Also, worth trying the use of managed-mode buffers. You'd need to call `-didModifyRange:` after filling them and synchronize them back using `-synchronizeResource:` at the end of the command buffer.

Comment: Well, the situation is even more complicated actually. Currently, the same host buffers are shared between CUDA and OpenCL and are pinned so that we can offload the data transfers to GPUs' DMA engines while doing other calculations on GPUs and CPUs. Now I am trying to understand how the Metal blends into the picture (Because it feels quite obvious that Apple has abandoned OpenCL). I'll give a try to the shared and managed modes as you suggest. BTW, do you know what is to be the trigger to start actual copying in case of shared metal buffers? A page fault on GPU?

Comment: Found this old thread on Khronos where people question the possibility of DMA transfer via Metal. https://forums.khronos.org/showthread.php/9649-Official-Vulkan-Feedback-API-for-High-efficiency-Graphics-and-Compute-on-GPUs/page23